# Meteor Http and https block on cloud9

Tags: meteor, https, cloud9-ide, adminlte

I have my meteor app running on cloud9. I have AdminLTE installed. When running the app on my local host, all is well. Running on cloud9-IDE I get the following browser error related to the AdminLTE package:

```
Mixed Content: The page at 'https://app-user.c9users.io/' 
was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure stylesheet 
'http://0.0.0.0:8080/packages/mfactory_admin-lte/css/AdminLTE.min.css'. 
This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
'http://0.0.0.0:8080/packages/mfactory_admin-lte/css/skins/skin-green.min.css'.
This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
```

How can I correct this? I red somewhere that I has to do with accessing http over https. I'm a bit clueless when it comes to https. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution. The environment variable must be forced.
Thus to run the app:

```
 ROOT_URL="https://app-username.c9users.io/" meteor --port $IP:$PORT
```